# Contextual Action Mode AppCompatActivity not show

Tags: android, contextual-action-bar, appcompatactivity

I have my activity extending AppCompatActivity, and I wish to set a contextual action bar on it.
So here is my onCreate method

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
MainActivity.this.startSupportActionMode(new ActionBarCallBack());
```

My ActionBarCallBack extend android.support.v7.view.ActionMode and I declared it like this

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contextual_menu, menu);
    return false;
}
```

The theme set on my manifest:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

MainActivity:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
</activity>
```

My onCreateActionMode trigger but the CAB never show.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does your theme really have no parent? I always thought it would have to inherit from (in this case) Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar

Comment: Well I edit my question with full style.xml and the manifest activity declaration

Comment: So it seems that your activity theme indeed has no parent. What happens if you add *parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"* ?

Comment: Gradle Build complain "No resource identifier found for attribute 'parent'". Just in case I saw that my toolbar inherit from AppTheme.PopupOverlay

Comment: Ok just saw the solution I edit my question. Thanks  0X0nosugar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here was the error

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contextual_menu, menu);
    return true; // Now it works
}
```

Set the windowActionModeOverlay to my Theme.NoActionBar

```
<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
```

Don't have to set the startActionMode() from my toolBar as I saw on over stackoverflow thread. On android.support.v7.view.ActionMode this line just work fine for me.

```
Main2Activity.this.startSupportActionMode(new ActionBarCallBack()); //android.support.v7.view.ActionMode
```

Comment: From documentation for [onCreateActionMode()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ActionMode.Callback.html#onCreateActionMode%28android.view.ActionMode,%20android.view.Menu%29) "Returns:
true if the action mode should be created, false if entering this mode should be aborted."

Answer (score 1):

You return **false** from implemented **onCreateActionMode** method in your ActionMode.Callback.

Try to change the return value to **true**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    // Inflate menu
    return true; //  <=====  MUST RETURN TRUE
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time but I've already answered it. I will check my answer.

Comment: @aiqency No problems, maybe it helps anybody in the future :)